# Creating a dictionary in a list from known variables

Tags: python, list, dictionary, nested-lists

I have some known values/variables a,b,c,d.

I would like to use these variables to create a dictionary in a list. I did the following but it did not work:

```
nestedlist['Name'] = a
nestedlist['Address']['StreetNumber'] = b
nestedlist['Address']['Zipcode']=c
nestedlist['Email']=d
```

I am getting the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    nestedlist['Address']['StreetNumber'] = b
    KeyError: 'Address'
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: Do you mean dictionary?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Before you do:

```
nestedlist['Address']['StreetNumber'] = b
nestedlist['Address']['Zipcode']=c
```

Do, this to create dictionary with key `Address`

```
nestedlist.setdefault("Address", dict())

# http://code.activestate.com/recipes/66516-add-an-entry-to-a-dictionary-unless-the-entry-is-a/
```

After that you can add key, value:

```
nestedlist['Address']['StreetNumber'] = b
nestedlist['Address']['Zipcode']=c
```

Comment: Why not just use a defaultdict?

Comment: Ya defaultdict is better option.

Answer (score 1):

Use a [defaultdict](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict):

```
from collections import defaultdict
blah = defaultdict(dict)
blah['Address']['Zipcode']=c
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to create `dict`,

```
nestedlist = {"name":None, "Address": {}, "Email": None}
```

Then you can assign `Address`

You are trying to assing `b` to `Address`'s `StreetNumber` key.

But `Address` is not exist, so it gives `KeyError`

Answer (score 0):

Firs of all its dictionary not list because if it was a list you'll get an `IndexError`.dictionary just create one key with assignment like :

```
>>> d={}
>>> d['a']=2
>>> d
{'a': 2}
```

And for create nested dictionary the value of preceding key should be defined as a dictionary so far!

```
>>> d['b']={}
>>> d['b']['c']=6
>>> d
{'a': 2, 'b': {'c': 6}}
```

Along side the other answers that suggests `defaultdict` and `setdefault` you can also create a nested dictionary with [dict comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries) :

```
>>> d={i:j if i!='b' else {'c':j} for i,j in [('b',4),('a',1),('d',3)]}
>>> d
{'a': 1, 'b': {'c': 4}, 'd': 3}
```